# Update a dictionary stored with cPickle without loading it into RAM

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

There is a loop running for a long time, creating data with each iteration. As the data tends to fill up the RAM after a while, I think it is a good idea to store it on disk. The first thing coming to my mind was to use cPickle for this to save the data as a binary file.

Here is the plan in detail. After each iteration, the new data is appended to a dictionary which has the iteration count as its key. This dictionary is then written to the disk. The procedure is repeated for each iteration.
The problem is that I do not know how to update the file on the disk. The only solution I know is to load the dictionary again, append the new data, and write it back. But in the end, this method makes no sense, as the dictionary has to be loaded into memory each time.

So is there a way to update a dictionary stored using cPickle without loading its contents into RAM again? Or is there another method to fulfil this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html was created.  It's a per-key on-disk pickle.